# How to find: $ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left\lfloor \frac{-1}{n}\right\rfloor $

Tags: limits

How to find:

$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left\lfloor  \frac{-1}{n}\right\rfloor =?$$

And :

$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left\lfloor  \frac{1}{n}\right\rfloor =?$$

---

My Try :

we know that :

$$\frac{-1}{n}-1 < \left\lfloor  \frac{-1}{n}\right\rfloor \leq \frac{-1}{n}$$

$$\frac{-(1+n)}{n} < \left\lfloor  \frac{1}{n}\right\rfloor \leq \frac{-1}{n}$$

NoW :

$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}   \frac{-1}{n} =0$$

$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \frac{-(1+n)}{n} =-1$$

So we can not use from Sandwich theorem . So what can we do?

Comment: For $n>1$, these functions are constant!

Comment: @Bernard. How to prove it?

Comment: Simply with the definition of the floor function. Is there any difficulty?

Comment: @Bernard. this way? if  $  \ \ : \to  \ \ 0<a<b$ then $0=\frac{0}{b}<\frac{a}{b}<\frac{b}{b}=1 \ \to  \lfloor \frac{a}{b} \rfloor=0$

Comment: Exactly. Be cautious with negative values.

Comment: @Bernar. this way? $n>1>0 \to -n<-1<0 \to -1=\frac{-n}{n} <\frac{-1}{n}< \frac{0}{n} =0$  So :

$$\lfloor \frac{-1}{n} \rfloor =-1$$

Comment: That's fine (except the formatting of the delimiters: you should add a pair of  `\Bigl ... \Bigr`).

Comment: @Bernard Thank you so much .

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I would insist that you try to evaluate $\lfloor1/n\rfloor$ for $n=1,2,3,4,5$ (that should be enough). From your question and your approach to it, it really looks as if you did not have a practical friendship with the function.